# How to test a usename and password whether present in LDAP?

Tags: ldap, ibm-datapower

I am basically using Datapower AAA policy and in that I have configured 'using LDAP to bind DN' as authenticate mechanism.

Now i have made rules and configured host and LDAP port

I have a user and Password to test whether it exist or not

How to test

Is there any gateway present to test(like MCCP)?

Comment: How is this linked to soapUI?

Comment: You need to provide a better explanation of your problem. Creating a AAA action to authenticate using LDAP bind is a basic AAA action, which you can inspect inside a probe when you run it in any service (mpgw or such).

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach this AAA Policy with some top level service objects [Web Service proxy, Multi Protocol Gateway, XML Firewall etc]. After that test the service to see if authentication is working fine or not? If you already did that, can you specify what is the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: Hi Ajitabh Actually it is showing internal error and when I am checking in probe there is nothing which is displayed

Comment: Have you checked logs. Can make logging level to debug and then copy paste the log contents over here so that I can see possible causes of errors. People usually get internal error on client side, while at the datapower device itself one should be able to see detailed trace of activity that is going on as part of transaction. Providing logs might be of some help here.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the user name and password and u can send over to LDAP server .
This you can achieve using an xsl to connect to LDAP and check the authentication.
We have pre-defined functions for LDAP search and authentication.

search : dp:ldap-search(address, port, bindDN, bindPassword, targetDN, attributeName, filter, scope, sslProxyProfile, ldapLBGroup, ldapVersion, ldapReadTimeout)

Auth  : dp:ldap-authen(bindDN, bindPassword, serverAddress, sslProxyProfileName, ldapLBGroup, "", ldapVersion, ldapReadTimeout)